# What is the name for a scrolling background?

Tags: html, css

I have seen this on several websites, where you have the foreground with the content, and in the background the image scrolls slower than the content, what is the name of this?

This is a demo, of the Parallax, but like this one, a lot of them seem to be this 4-5 pane deal, I was looking for just one image type thing

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html

Like this
http://www.elderscrolls.com/

Comment: can you send some links.. where you have seen

Comment: `parallax-scrolling` i think is what you are looking for....

Comment: this needs to be closed . Not even a question to be asked here . you can google it for sure and that will help better .

Answer (score 6):

you are talking about a parallax effect

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

Comment: You may also have a look at [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/).